# How can I programmatically click a button on a website

Tags: html, go, button, click, element

I know in some different codes it's like `await page.click`, but I cannot find out how to do it in `go`. I'm trying to create a fully automated checkout script. Here's what I have so far, it just opens the website

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    err := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "start", "chrome.exe", "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/pny-geforce-gt1030-2gb-pci-e-3-0-graphics-card-black/5901353.p?skuId=5901353gi").Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)

    }
```

Comment: There's nothing in the standard library that provides that functionality out of the box. I believe you'll need something like https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp, how exactly to use that to trigger a button click I don't know, you'll have to wait for someone more knowledgeable or you can do research yourself by reading the documentation and looking at examples on github.

Comment: I just noticed that the github chromedp org/user (or whatever its called) itself has an [examples](https://github.com/chromedp/examples) repository which contains the [click](https://github.com/chromedp/examples/blob/master/click/main.go) and [click2](https://github.com/chromedp/examples/blob/master/click2/main.go) examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click button with Chromedp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316689/click-button-with-chromedp)

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna check `https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp` package to control Chrome DevTool.

[More Examples](https://github.com/chromedp/examples)

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    // create chrome instance
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(
        context.Background(),
        chromedp.WithLogf(log.Printf),
    )
    defer cancel()

    // create a timeout
    ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, 15*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    // navigate to a page, wait for an element, click
    var example string
    err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Navigate(`https://golang.org/pkg/time/`),
        // wait for footer element is visible (ie, page is loaded)
        chromedp.WaitVisible(`body > footer`),
        // find and click "Expand All" link
        chromedp.Click(`#pkg-examples > div`, chromedp.NodeVisible),
        // retrieve the value of the textarea
        chromedp.Value(`#example_After .play .input textarea`, &example),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Go's time.After example:\n%s", example)
}
```

Comment: I know this probably a dumb question but it says could not import github.com/chromedp/chromedp (cannot find package "github.com/chromedp/chromedp" in any of C:\Program Files\Go\src\github.com\chromedp\chromedp (from $GOROOT) C\src\github.com\chromedp\chromedp (from $GOPATH) \Users\brand\go\src\github.com\chromedp\chromedp (from $GOPATH) -- What can I do to fix this?

Comment: @Brandon https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+could+not+import

Comment: no worries. you need to install the package.

`go get -u github.com/chromedp/chromedp`

you need to run: `go mod init` then `go mod tidy`

Comment: Honestly you guys are so awesome! I have been having this issue for the last 3 months and just recently found out about stack overflow.  So my next question is where should I input the element to click the specific button in my code?   chromedp.Click(`#pkg-examples > div`, chromedp.NodeVisible),
   // retrieve the value of the textarea

Comment: yes you can use css selector or id of the button you want to clicks. checkout examples on github

Comment: ok how do I find other examples? I tried to look up everything buy cannot find other examples, again thanks!